# How do I properly emit javascript in Kynetx rule?

Tags: javascript, krl

I have code from my ad network that I am trying insert into an existing rule to call an ad from the server and place it into a div.

The javascript code is given to me to, normally, to embed in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var z=document.createElement("script");z.type="text/javascript";z.async=true;z.src="http://engine.adzerk.net/z/12735/azk1_2_5";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);</script>
```

And then the div portion that is placed in the body:

```
<div id="azk1"></div>
```

The div is being placed like with this:

```
rule NAME {
    select when pageview "url"
    pre {
        ad = '<div id="azk1"></div>';
    }
    replace_inner("#ad-slot-1", ad);

}
```

First, is the div placement done correctly? and second, how do I need to format the javascript for the rule? Do I use a global emit? can I store it on another server and call it? If so, how should that be formatted?

Thx

Comment: Your div placement is correct, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it two ways. The **first** is the [`use resource` syntax](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Use_resource). Put this in the global block:

```
use javascript resource "http://yourserver.com/path/to/javascript.js"
```

Then put the JavaScript like normal in that file.

The **second** option is to use an emit in the rule itself. It goes in the action block, so your new rule would look like this:

```
rule NAME {
    select when pageview "url"
    pre {
        ad = '<div id="azk1"></div>';
    }
    {
        emit <|
            // Your JavaScript here
        |>;
        replace_inner("#ad-slot-1", ad);
    }
}
```

The JavaScript you would put in the file or in that `emit` block is everything between the `<script>` tags in the code you originally gave.